# Deploy Redmine 4.x on Plesk-Server: ArgumentError: string contains null byte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, ubuntu-18.04, plesk-onyx

Im following this Tutorial to Deploy a Redmine Instance on my vServer: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001670625

I get an Error at Point 14.2 "Insert RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate to the Task parameters field and click Run."

Redmine-Version: 4.0.4
Ruby Version: 2.6.3-p62

```html
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22:in `new'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22:in `mysql2_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in `new_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795:in `acquire_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in `checkout'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1014:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in '
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/plesk/ruby/2.6.3/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/var/www/vhosts/redmine.domain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake:23:in `
'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I don't know what else to do. In the forum of Plesk and Redmine nobody could help me so far...

Comment: A corrupt file perhaps?

Comment: As I can see, on the Plesk tutorial it says Redmine 3.4 not Redmine 4.x, please retry with Redmine 3.4...

Comment: Double check the file `database.yml` you've edited on Step 8. Download it and make sure there's no suspicious *null bytes*

Comment: @AleksandarPavić That's exactly what it was. With v3.4 it works according to instructions — Thank you so much!

Comment: @Eyeslandic i don't think so. I can open the file without any problems

Comment: @LyzardKyng Ive checked it. Nothing to see there...

Answer (score -1):

### **Aleksandar Pavić** was right:

> As I can see, on the Plesk tutorial it says Redmine 3.4 not Redmine
>   4.x, please retry with Redmine 3.4...

---

With Redmine 3.4.X it worked! Thank you a lot!